# SetContent error in DOM Parser

Tags: c++, qt, dom

I am trying to read and write a XML file, I'm using `DOM` parser to read the XML file and `xmlputget` to write.
Here's the code

```js
void MainWindow::on_Save_button_clicked()
{
   XML();
   XML1();
   XML2();
   XML3();
   XML4();
   XML5();
}
void::MainWindow::XML()
{
    QString path = ui->lineEdit_7->text();
    QFile inFile(path );
        if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );

        }

        QDomDocument dom;
        if( !dom.setContent( &inFile ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to parse the file into a DOM tree." );
            inFile.close();

        }
        
            QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
            QDomNodeList node = docElem.elementsByTagName("ABC");
            QDomNode parentNode = node.at(0).parentNode();
            parentNode.removeChild(node.at(0));
            QFile outFile(path);
            if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
            {
                qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
            }
            QTextStream stream( &outFile );
            stream << dom.toString();
            outFile.close();
            QXmlGet xmlget;
            xmlget.load(path);
            xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
            QXmlPut xmlput(xmlget);
            xmlput.putString("ABC", "abc");
            xmlput.save(path);
        
}
void MainWindow::XML1()
{

    QString path = ui->lineEdit_7->text();
    QFile inFile(path );
        if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );

        }
        QDomDocument dom;
        if( !dom.setContent( &inFile ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to parse the file into a DOM tree." );
            inFile.close();

        }
        
            QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
            QDomNodeList node = docElem.elementsByTagName("FILE");
            QDomNode parentNode = node.at(0).parentNode();
            parentNode.removeChild(node.at(0));

            QFile outFile(path);
            if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
            {
                qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
            }
            QTextStream stream( &outFile );
            stream << dom.toString();
            outFile.close();
            QXmlGet xmlget;
            xmlget.load(path);
            xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
            QXmlPut xmlput(xmlget);
            xmlput.putString("FIle", "file");
            xmlput.save(path);
        
}
void MainWindow::XML2()
{
    QString path = ui->lineEdit_7->text();
    QFile inFile(path);
        if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );

        }
        QDomDocument dom;
        if( !dom.setContent( &inFile ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to parse the file into a DOM tree." );
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
        
            QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
            QDomNodeList node = docElem.elementsByTagName("Main");
            QDomNode parentNode = node.at(0).parentNode();
            parentNode.removeChild(node.at(0));
            QFile outFile(path);
            if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
            {
                qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
            }
            QTextStream stream( &outFile );
            stream << dom.toString();
            outFile.close();
            QXmlGet xmlget;
            xmlget.load(path);
            xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
            QXmlPut xmlput(xmlget);
            xmlput.putString("main", "main");
            xmlput.save(path);
        }
}
void MainWindow::XML3()
{
    QString path = ui->lineEdit_7->text();
    QFile inFile(path );
        if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );

        }

        QDomDocument dom;
        if( !dom.setContent( &inFile ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to parse the file into a DOM tree." );
            inFile.close();
            return;
        }
          
            QDomElement docElem = dom.documentElement();
            QDomNodeList node = docElem.elementsByTagName("Root");
            QDomNode parentNode = node.at(0).parentNode();
            parentNode.removeChild(node.at(0));
            QFile outFile(path);
            if( !outFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
            {
                qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
            }
            QTextStream stream( &outFile );
            stream << dom.toString();
            outFile.close();
            QXmlGet xmlget;
            xmlget.load(path);
            xmlget.findAndDescend("HEADER");
            QXmlPut xmlput(xmlget);
            xmlput.putString("Root", "root");
            xmlput.save(path);
}
```

When my program goes to `XML` it doesn't have any error, but when it goes to `XML1`and further, everytime it goes into

`if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text ) )
        {
            qDebug( "Failed to open file for reading." );
            return;
        }`

and I'm getting error `Failed to open file for reading.`. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps it's the problem that inFile isn't closed in XML()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open the same file multiple times with "read and write" rights without closing at the end of each function.

Either close you inFile to release the r/w tokens at the end of each XMLn function.

```
inFile.close();
```

Either open your file with only "read" right

```
if( !inFile.open( QIODevice::Read | QIODevice::Text ) )
```